# wxwidgets vs gtkmm with my requirements

Tags: c++, windows, linux, wxwidgets, gtkmm

I'm implementing a GUI program (a cards game) in gtkmm (at the moment). I want that my program runs well at least under Windows and Linux (GTK). Mac OS X would be a plus, although not required. Although I'm using gtkmm, I have some concerns with it. 
More concretely:

- Lack of support for connecting signals at runtime.
- The API for treeview is horrible in the sense that you need to make your own classes
  in c++ code every tie you have a new Treemodel.

These two things get a lot in my way when implementing GUI code. My questions are, if I switch to wxwidgets:

1.- Is it possible to connect signals at runtime?
2.- Is the ListCtrl API from Wxwidgets comfortable to use in your opinion?
3.- Is there a decent gui builder (preferably free, but not required) in which I don't have to connect signals by hand in c++ code? This is quite important to keep controller and view code separated.
4.- Is there an alternative to wxwidgets which is better and looks good under gtkmm, besides working on Windows. I'd rather not use qt with its preprocessing step

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused by your complaint that gtkmm (libsigc++) doesn't support connecting signals at run time.  Aren't all signals connected at run time?  Can you give a more specific example to help me understand what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean exactly that. What I meant is that you cannot bind signals from glade in gtkmm because they are type-safe. Unfortunately, sometimes it's quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible.
2. ListCtrl if just fine to use, and you will maybe find some nicer alternative (UltimateListCtrl, wxGrid...).
3. [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/).
4. Not that I know of.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Is wxFormBuilder a good choice? How does it compare to wxDesigner?

Comment: Well, I pretty much tried all of them and I like wxFormBuilder the best. I've been using it for about a year. But what works for me doesn't have to work for you, try them out and see for yourself.